# Proving second derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm asked to prove a theorem (if that is the right word) about double derivatives. I'm still struggling with understanding Leibniz notation and I could use a push in the right direction. It's easy enough for me to differentiate the function when I write it down as $f(g(x))$ but not so much with Leibniz notation.

The problem is as follows: If $y = f(u)$ and $u = g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable functions, show that:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2y}{du^2}\frac{du}{dx}^2 + \frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$

Could someone fill me in on the details of each part of this equation? For example, why is the second derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ written as $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ instead of $\frac{d^2y}{d^2x}$?

Thanks!

Comment: The notation you find easy is SIA; you could just do it all in that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your last question is that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}y$ so the second derivative is $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y$. This should answer the first question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f\circ g$ and $y(x)=f(g(x))$, with $u:=g(x)$. Then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}:=\frac{d(f\circ g)}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx};$$

whenever we write $\frac{df}{du}$ we mean $\frac{df(u)}{du}$, i.e. $\frac{dy}{du}$. Introducing the function $h(u):=\frac{df(u)}{du}$ we arrive at

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(h(u)\frac{dg}{dx}\right)=
\frac{dh}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}+
h\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\\
\frac{dh}{du}\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}+
\frac{df}{du}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2f}{du^2}\left(\frac{dg}{dx}\right)^2+
\frac{df}{du}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2+
\frac{dy}{du}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}.$$